# how to check what shape key connected to bone?

Tags: objects, rigging, drivers, shape-keys

i'm quite new to use the shape key drivers so here my question,

by clicking the object that have shape key drivers you can know which bone connected to it by seeing the drivers tab

[image]

but how can you know what shape key drivers connected to the bone you clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only move the bone and read in the properties panel, shape keys tab, which is (or are) driven.

[image]

Comment: no, what i mean is where can i see the shape key drivers information from the selected bone not the selected object

Comment: Yes, I mean that you will have to move the bone (in my example named "L"), see in the properties panel that the value changed in the shape key named "eye down L", go to the driver editor and select "eye down L". There isn't a shorter way.

Comment: hmm i see in order too know what shape keys connected to it first u must move the bone n then look what shape key changed in the object properties. but unfortunately as you said there isn't a shorter way, even though i move the bone only partly shape key changed (not all the shaped key from bone driver) as the direction it moved, it's kind of harsh to check it one by one..

and thanks anyway josh, it's help me